# How best to retain self for delegate with ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

Imagine three classes.  ClassA and ClassB are mine.  The third class is a UIViewController whose code I can't modify:

In ClassA:

```
- (void) aMethod
{
    ClassB *classBInstance = [[[ClassB alloc] init] goWithOptions:options];
}
```

`ClassBInstance` is retained only for the lifetime of `aMethod`.

In ClassB:

```
- (void) goWithOptions
{
    AUIViewController *avcInstance = [[AUIViewController alloc] init];
    avcInstance.delegate = self;
    [viewController pushViewController:avcInstance animated: YES];    // this returns immediately, but we need self to be retained until the delegate is done with it
}

- (void) cleanupCalledByDelegate //
{
    // cleanup
}
```

when the `-goWithOptions` method is called, `avcInstance` is retained by the callee, but self, which is passed to the `delegate` is not.  That means that as soon as `-goWithOptions` returns, and `aMethod` is done, then the `classBInstance` is released, and the `delegate` for `avcInstance` is no longer valid.

Ideally, I'd like to tie the ownership of `classBInstance` (self in ClassB) to `avcInstance`;  when the `avcInstance` gets released, then `classBInstance` or the delegate is released.

Alternatively, I can cleanup `classBInstance` in -`cleanupCalledByDelegate`, which is called before `avcInstance` is released.

How best to handle this?  I'd rather not make `ClassB *classBInstance` a property of ClassA, because then I would have to get it to release `classBInstance`, and I'd prefer to handle that in ClassB.  If this were the best solution, I would use blocks and in ClassA, pass a completion block:

```
{
    classBInstance = nil;
}
```

to `-goWithOptions`, which I would call in `-cleanupCalledByDelegate`.  Is this the right way to handle this?

Comment: One of the disadvantages of arc is you don't have as much control. Retain/release is now tied to properties. To retain/release something you have to add another property.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - not just to properties.  strong ivars too, to scope, and associations.

Comment: @TomSwift right, point is, it is now tied to a named variable making it more cumbersome to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to "tie the ownership of classBInstance (self in ClassB) to avcInstance", you can use objective-c object association:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

objc_setAssociatedObject( avcInstance, "my_association", classBInstance, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN );
```

Furthermore, if you need more convenience for accessing the classBInstance later you could wrap this association code into a category extension that exposes classBInstance as a property on avcInstance.

Comment: You can do that (+1), but it smells like bad app design.  If ClassA needs a more formal relationship with ClassB than the standard weak delegate, then it should be modeled as a more formal relationship and managed explicitly.

Comment: But isn't it ClassB that needs the more formal relationship with the picker?  Class A just wants some class to do a task and doesn't want to be bothered by the how.  Class B is the one that needs to link itself with the UIViewController picker which has the need for a delegate and yet doesn't retain the delegate.

Comment: For example, ClassA wants some information displayed.  It doesn't care how it is displayed, or whether the display succeeds or not.  It makes a call, and goes along its merry way.  In fact, ClassA may want to make many of these display calls and assumes that ClassB will manage the queuing - that means that a single property in ClassA isn't the answer, and we either rely on creating unique instances on the stack or create and array property to track ClassB instances.

Comment: Since ClassB decides how it displays the information and has to handle the delegate callbacks, etc., so it would be nice to have ClassB and the UIViewController handle the retention, rather than expose that task to another class.

Comment: I tend to agree with @bbum that it 'smells like bad design' but that's your call.  If you're just being pragmatic and can justify your pattern then it may be fine.  Without having more insight it's hard to pass judgement, IMO.

Comment: @TomSwift It could be bad design, but I'm trying to find a way to keep ClassA from having to manage an async process.  After all, I created ClassB to isolate the display of the data from ClassA.  I don't want ClassA to have keep track of a single or multiple instances of ClassB.  Imagine that when using NSLog, you had to create and maintain a property for each NSLog and had to nil that property after you knew NSLog was done with it.  I want that kind of convenience of NSLog today, without the caller having to do the extra work.

Comment: Normally, I'd resort to making the delegate be strong, but here I have no control over the class the delegate is defined in.

Comment: @mahboudz The best performing app is often the one that ships first.  If it works, it works.  But it is still a "code smell".  It is likely to cause problems in the future or otherwise be a point of confusion.  In particular, it risks having multiple such "background" things active simultaneously because of the loose binding between UI and operation.   For these kinds of situations, I typically invest in the additional complexity of some kind of a queue manager and/or central agent that can keep track of such things.  Makes debugging and refactoring easier.

Comment: Just create a table where your delegate object is the key and the object you want to hold on to is the value. A ref will be held in the dict until the delegate calls a method to cleanup by removing the dict entry.